# how to set default value in ionic 2 input?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

**I want to set a default value in ionic input .. please help**

address.html file code

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>{{'address.email'|translate}}</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="user_email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

[default mail like example@gmail.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7NHT.png)

adderss.ts

```
    ionViewDidEnter() {
    if (this.isCache) this.getData();
    else this.isCache = true;
}
getData() {
    this.storageMul.get(['login', 'useBilling', 'user']).then(val => {
        if (val['login']) this.login = val['login'];
        if (val['useBilling'] == false) this.useBilling = false;
        else this.useBilling = true;
        if (val['user']) {
            this.data = val['user'];

        }
        this.reset();
    });
}
reset() {
    this.formAddress.patchValue({
        billing_first_name: this.data["billing_first_name"],
        billing_address_1: this.data["billing_address_1"],
        billing_phone: this.data["billing_phone"],
        user_email: this.data["user_email"],
        shipping_first_name: this.data["shipping_first_name"],
        shipping_address_1: this.data["shipping_address_1"],
    });
```

please help me out!!

Comment: What is not working? Is there an issue somewhere? any errors?

Comment: I still don't really understand what exactly you are trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

You would do this with a normal `[(ngModel)]` bind.

```
<ion-label floating>{{'address.email'|translate}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user_email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Inside your TypeScript you would set the variable to a specific value when the page loads

*.component.ts

```
constructor() {
    this.user_email = 'some@value.com';
}
```

This way when the user enters the screen, the value will be the default value and it still allows the user to update that value.

Comment: I can not understand ... Sir ... please any way to put default value by this code `user_email: [''],`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "placeholder".

`<ion-input placeholder="email@place.com"></ion-input>`

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/

Comment: So you're trying to prefill the form with a specified value?

Comment: if you just need to prefill it: `value="{{data.user_email}}"` or something to that nature