# inputting default value inside input text in ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I set a default value inside input text in ionic.

What I tried so far:

```
<ion-item class="mylist">
 <ion-input type="text" placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="userData" name="name" #name></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

and

```
 <ion-item class="mylist">
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="name" value="{{userData}}" name="name" #name></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

None of them seemed to work.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set default value in ionic 2 input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556212/how-to-set-default-value-in-ionic-2-input)